# Multiple IF AND statements excel

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

I want to know if it's possible to have multiple `IF` statements in one cell.

What I am looking at is this.  I have text in Columns A and B.   What I want is to check whether Columns A and B match two (constant) phrases, and, if they do, populate Column C with a third phrase.  Here is my example.

[image]

So as you can see from the screen shot, when the words Active Military and Active come together I want it to say "Recall and Update to Military" in Column C. Then the next one down says No Documents and Active.  I want that to return in the 3rd cell TWO.

Comment: Welcome to Super User! We can help, but not here to do it for you. Please share us what you have researched and attempted to resolve this. It may be helpful to read **[ask]** to improve your question. If you need to share a screenshot, please upload to a file share site, then add a link. We will embed the image for you.

Comment: The appropriate solution depends somewhat on how many combinations you have defined.  You can hard code nested IFs, like Graham's solution, but this will get messy (and there are nesting limits), if you have a large number of targets.  With many targets, you might do better to create a lookup list  Concatenate the relevant A and B combinations for the lookup table.  Then use INDEX/MATCH or VLOOKUP to search the list for the concatenated A&B values.

Answer (score 0):

This seems fairly straightforwards - yes, you can have nested IF statements in a cell - for example in cell C1 you could have:

=If(AND(A1 = "Active Military",B1 = "Active"),"(RECALL AND UPDATE TO MILITARY)",IF(AND(A1 = "No Documents", B1 = "Active"),"TWO","*whatever you want to put if neither of these are valid, or start a third IF statement*"))

Copy this down column C to use with other rows.

As you have "Active" in both B1 cells you could change this to

=IF(B1 = "Active", If(A1 = "Active Military","(RECALL AND UPDATE TO MILITARY)",IF(A1 = "No Documents", "TWO","*whatever you want to put if neither of these are valid etc.*")), "Not Active")

You will then get the message "Not Active", if cell B1 is not equal to "Active", otherwise it works as the first option.

You can, of course, amend the text in the above statements to whatever you need them to be.

Comment: Excel has a limited number of nested IF's it will accept.  This may not work  for many conditions.  It would be better to use the `AND` or `OR` function in conjunction with an `IF` statement.